# Expectation values using qiskit

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, matrix-representation

Expectation values can be calculated using

$\bf{Matrix}$ $\bf{mechanics}:$

$A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ and eigenstates $\Phi_j$. Then the expectation value of $A$ with respect to a state
$\Psi=\sum_j c_j\Phi_j$ is calculated as

$\left\langle A\right\rangle_{\Psi}=\left\langle \Psi |A|\Psi\right\rangle=\sum_j \lambda_j c_j|\left\langle\Psi|\Phi_j \right\rangle |^2=\sum_j \lambda_j |c_j|^2$, where
$c_j=\left\langle\Phi_j|\Psi \right\rangle$

or

$\bf{Quantum}$ $\bf{algorithms}:$

The state $\Psi$ is created by a unitary transform V, such that $|{\Psi}\rangle=V|0,0,0...\rangle$.

Therefore $\left\langle A\right\rangle_{\Psi}=\left\langle \Psi |A|\Psi\right\rangle=\left\langle 0,0,0...|V^\dagger A V|0,0,0...\right\rangle$.

So we repeatedly measure the state  $V^\dagger A V|{0,0,0...}\rangle$ in the computational basis and determine the probabilty to measure $|{0,0,0...}\rangle$, which yields $\left\langle A\right\rangle_{\Psi}$.

So I create a state $\Psi=V|{0,0,0...}\rangle$ and operator A and compute

print(psi.adjoint().compose(A).compose(psi).eval().real)

which agrees with results from Matrix Mechanics.

However, if I build a circuit from operators $V^\dagger,A,V$ and measure the probabilities for  $|{0,0,0...}\rangle$, the results do not agree. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ isn't actually a quantum gate because it isn't necessarily unitary, so $V^\dagger AV| \mathbf{0} \rangle$ is not even a valid quantum circuit. Suppose that $A$ *is* unitary (for example a Pauli product); the probability of measuring $\mathbf{0}$ *still* isn't $\langle A \rangle_\psi := \langle \mathbf{0} | V^\dagger AV | \mathbf{0} \rangle$, but rather $\langle A \rangle_{\psi}^2$. To see this, suppose
$$
|\phi\rangle = [\phi_0, \phi_1, ... \phi_{n-1}]
$$
Then $\langle 0 | \phi \rangle = \phi_0$, which is generally a *complex number*; the *probability* of measuring $\mathbf{0}$ is a real number $|\phi_0|^2$.

To measure the expectation value $\langle A \rangle_\psi$ of an observable $A$ in the state $| \psi \rangle := V| \mathbf{0} \rangle$:

1. Construct the circuit to prepare the state $| \psi \rangle$
2. Apply gates to the end of your circuit that will *rotate the state* into the *diagonal basis* of $A$
3. Run the circuit and read the measurements
4. Calculate the mean of the *eigenvalues* corresponding to each measurement result

Notice that at no point do we ever directly use the operators $A$ or $V^\dagger$.

For example, suppose your observable is $Y_0 X_1$. The unitaries that diagonalize $Y$ and $X$ are $HS^\dagger$ and $H$ respectively; to see this, let's look at $X$:
$$
\langle \psi | X | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | H^\dagger ZH| \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | HZH| \psi \rangle
$$
As such, you need to add the gate sequence $[Z, S, H]$ to qubit 0 and $H$ to qubit 1. Suppose then that you run 10 shots, getting the results
$$[11, 00, 00, 01, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
00, 00]$$
The eigenvalues corresponding to the outcomes $[00, 01, 10, 11]$ are $[1, -1, -1, 1]$ respectively, so your estimated expectation is
$$
\langle A \rangle_\psi \approx \frac{1 + 1 + 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1}{10} = 0.4
$$

However, in Qiskit, you don't have to add the basis rotations or do any calculations with the measurements; instead, an [Estimator](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit-ibm-runtime/qiskit_ibm_runtime.Estimator) takes care of all that for you:

```python
circuit = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
circuit...  # build circuit implementing V
estimator = Estimator(...) 
op = ...  # observable A
expectation_value = estimator.run(circuit , op).result().values
```

If you do decide to do the calculations from the measurements manually, remember that Qiskit results are little-endian; the results are ordered from the last qubit to the first.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot. I have to put some thought into this.

Comment: I want to learn as much as possible from my mistakes. I understand the method that you suggest. I do not understand though why the method that I suggest does not work in case that A is a unitary operator. Is there somethig wrong with the general idea? I checked my code for the case that A=Identity, then the result makes sense since i get the $|0,0,..\rangle$ state as output.

Comment: Edited my answer for additional clarification! Remember that the probability of a given basis state is the _squared modulus_ of the amplitude; $P(k) = |\psi_k|^2$, not $\psi_k$.